# Spectral Theorem for a Complex Vector Space and corollary

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, diagonalization

[image: Here is the Spectral Theorem]

When it says orthogonal projections it must mean they are orthogonal with each other otherwise if it meant they were orthogonal lin transformations then they would be invertible- the only invertible projection is the identity map and if they were all equal to that they couldnt possibly sum to give the identity.

Here is the corollary I can't see why it should follow
[image]

ok it's not really a corollary but it uses the previous theorem. I PARTICULARLY CANNOT UNDERSTAND THE FIRST LINE OF THE PROOF- HOW HAS IT BEEN DEDUCED THAT V IS THE DIRECT SUM OF ALL THOSE EIGENSPACES WITH ALL THOSE $\lambda_i$ DISTINCT?

Answer (score 1):

Those $V_{\lambda_i}$ are the images of the $E_i$ in the theorem.

The way that the spectral theorem is usually stated is that for a normal, complex operator $T: V \to V$, there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

In this proof, $V_{\lambda_i}$ is the span of the orthonormal set of eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

Comment: Sorry- I can't see how they are the images or where we have used 1),2) or 3)

Comment: Let $V_{\lambda_i} = \im(E_i).$ Use 2 to show that $V = \oplus_{i=1}^r V_{\lambda_i}$. Then use 1 to show that each $V_{\lambda_i}$ is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

Comment: I can see why that thing is a sum but not a direct sum (why is it only 0 in the intersection?)- also I feel like I need to use the fact that the intersection is 0 in order to prove using the help of 1 that $Im E_i= Ker(T-\lambda_i)$ I will accept answer but I really don't understand this.

Comment: Ok I can see why $Im(E_i)\subseteq Ker(T-\lambda_i)$ . Suppose $v$ belongs to the LHS. Then $ \exists v_1$ s.t $E_iv_1=v$ Then $(T-\lambda_i)v=(T-\lambda_i)E_iv_1= \lambda_iE_iv_1-\lambda_iE_iv_1=0$ so $v$ is in $Ker(T-\lambda_i)$

Comment: I cannot show that $Ker(T−λ_i)⊆Im(E_i)$